# Spring Data JPA - how to set transient fields after retrieval

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

After an entity is fetched using the `JpaRepository` methods of Spring Data JPA, e.g. `findOne`, `findBy...`, etc., I was wondering what would be the best way to automatically execute some custom code, say to initialize some transient fields.

In other words, suppose I have a User entity with a `fullName` transient field, which should be set as a concatenation of `firstName` and `lastName` after fetching from the database, what should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, if all you want if full name just write a method that concatenates forename/surname  on the fly. It doesn't have to be a field.

If you really need to do some processing on Entity load then register a `@PostLoad` entity lifecycle callback:

```
public class MyEntity{

     @PostLoad
     //invoked by framework on entity load.
     public void doStuff(){
         fullName =  forename + " " + surname;   
     }

     //alternative
     public String getFullName(){
         return forename + " " + surname;
     }
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Example_of_Entity_event_annotations

Comment: Thanks, @PostLoad is working well. fullName was just an example - I'd use it for more lengthy initializations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@Access(AccessType.Property)`  for setting transient fields ideally.

You have to mention `@Access(AccessType.Property)` on the setter method normally and then you can set value of that transient field in that setter method.

**Alternatively in case of repositories , you can very well write a `JPQL` something like this.**

@Query("SELECT new Hello(a.x*a.y,a.x,a.y)FROM Hello a WHERE t.value = :value")

and then in the constructor set the value of this `transient variable` with `a.x*a.y`

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried myself but it seems that the [@PostLoad](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PostLoad.html) annotation may help you to execute code to change the state of a business object after retrieving it from the database.

But in your concrete case I would simply create a method getFullName that concatenates firstName and secondName without storing the value in the bean.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I found a proper solution for my use case which worked without using the Transient annotation at all.

What I did is creating two classes, one of which is a subset of the other. Both classes refer the same db-table but the subset class just doesn´t include the transient property.
So all my related entities refer to the subset-class. But when I explicity want to set or get the transient property, I use the original superset class.

```
// SUPERSET-CLASS
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_object")
public class DataObject {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(nullable=false, name="id")
   public Long id; 
   public String name;
   
   @JsonIgnore
   @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   public byte[] data;
   
 }

// SUBSET-CLASS
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_object")
public class DataObject_Subset {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(nullable=false, name="id")
   public Long id; 
   public String name;
 }
```